# Append existing data to table with identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

SQL Server 2014: I am importing a table that is living in an old SQL Server to a new server. What I did was download the table to MS Access, then uploaded it to the new server (different environments).

The problem is that on upload, my primary key and auto increment are dropped. PK was easy to fix, and I was able to add a new identity column, but now I cannot append to the identity column as an error saying `IDENTITY_INSERT` is `ON`. So I turned it off, but still getting the same error.

Any ideas work a workaround?

Comment: What is "SQL 2014"?

Comment: Read the error more carefuly.  It did not Say that identity inserat was on.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation for INDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON. If a table already has this property set to ON, and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table, SQL Server returns an error message that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.

If you already tried turning it off for the other table, you might be in a transaction - try issuing a `COMMIT`.